# meteor npm install --save babel-runtime error

Tags: meteor

receiving error below while trying to run meteor npm install --save babel-runtime.  appreciate any suggestions.

meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at /Users/t3/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.1bvf0xf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm:19:21
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/t3/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.1bvf0xf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm:79:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using wrong/different/incompatible version of node. Try switching to `4.*` branch with nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Then after you install nvm, run something like

```
nvm install 4.8.2
nvm use 4.8.2
```

Then try npm install again